# Gem overriding layout for controller doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm currently developing a gem that handles mobile devices.

The controller looks like this:

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  has_mobile_views
```

And the code of the gem looks like this:

```
module MobileViewsController
  module ClassMethods
    def has_mobile_views(args={})
      class_eval do
        if request.subdomain == 'm'
          request.format = :mobile_html
          layout Proc.new { |controller| controller.request.subdomain == 'm' ? 'mobile_application' : 'application'}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The format works just fine, it renders xxx.mobile_html.haml files nicely but what doesn't work is loading the layout. It doesn't load any layout whatsoever.

But on the other hand when I change

```
 controller.request.subdomain == 'm' ? 'mobile_application' : 'application'
```

to

```
 controller.request.subdomain == 'm' ? 'xmobile_application' : 'application'
```

It throws an error that xmobile_application cannot be found so it must at least look for it.

This also doesn't work:

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  has_mobile_views
  layout 'mobile_application'
```

However when I change the PageController to

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  layout 'mobile_application'
```

The layout is being loaded and rendered correctly.

Anyone an idea what could be wrong here or what to change in the gem to not screw up the layout?

Comment: I think you're missing `end` for `if` condition. And I believe `request` is accessible inside controller instance and not class, so this condition inside `class_eval` doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have

- `mobile_html` mime type registered in `config/initializers/mime-types.rb`
- your mobile layout in `app/views/layouts/mobile_application.mobile_html.erb`
- `MobileViews` module included in your `ApplicationController`

that does the job:

```
module MobileViewsController

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def has_mobile_views(args = {})
      before_filter Proc.new {
        request.format = :mobile_html if request.subdomain == 'm'
      }

      layout Proc.new { |c|
        c.request.subdomain == 'm' ? 'mobile_application' : 'application'
      }
    end

  end

end
```